# Request link in python - HTTP Basic: Access denied

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to download ECOSTRESS data from the usgs as .h5 file from the following link in python:

https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ECOB/ECOSTRESS/ECO2LSTE.001/2022.08.30/ECOSTRESS_L2_LSTE_23529_005_20220830T064558_0601_02.h5

When I manually open this link in my browser on my Mac, the following window appears:

[image]

Accordingly, you must log-in to get access to the stored file. I know my login credentials, so thats not a problem. I tried different libraries to download the file in python, but after all my research the requests library seems to be the most convenient. This is my approach to download the file:
`response = requests.get(url,auth=(config.username,config.password))`
The username and password is both stored as a string. My problem is, that everytime `response.content` is equal to `b'HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n'`.

Another approach I tried, was to embedd the credentials in the url, but this also didn't worked:
`response = requests.get('https://username:password@e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ECOB/ECOSTRESS/ECO2LSTE.001/2022.08.30/ECOSTRESS_L2_LSTE_23529_005_20220830T064558_0601_02.h5')`

So far, I already tried a post instead of a get request, I triple checked my user credenials etc. etc. Since it works perfectly fine manually on my browser, I would say there must be a way to do that in python. Since I have to download a large amount of files, doing it manually is also no option.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem or had similiar problems?

Comment: what type of auth you are applying  and website need, check that, otherwise you can use selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to download the file you want you need to do it in 2 steps:

1. First make an unauthorized request -> The server returns a 401 Unauthorized response with a redirect URL that tells you where to make the authorised request to
2. make the authorized request with the new url

here is how it looks:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = (self.username, self.password)
    # Get the redirection URL: Notice the use of requests and not the session
    r1 = requests.get(url) 
    r = s.get(r1.url, allow_redirects=True) #use the returned url of the first call
```